# Error handling with python-shell: how to avoid shutting down the server?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have local node.js server running. In my server.js, I'm using python-shell with the following formula.

```
var {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');


import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';
 
let options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonPath: 'path/to/python',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'], 
  scriptPath: 'path/to/my/scripts',
  args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
};
 
PythonShell.run('my_websearch.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

My Python script makes a web search. Most of the time this all works fine, but when it faces a broken link, the following error shuts down the whole server. I want to avoid this of course, but I was wondering how. If I move this python-shell code to my index.js, it complains about requiring python-shell. What happens if I just delete the error line from the code?

I'm quite new to web apps and even newer to python-shell so warm thanks for any tips!

Comment: You need to handle errors inside python script by adding appropriate [`try.. except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: try...except did the trick!